# How can I capture multiple variables using pattern matching?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For example:

```
List(1,2,3,4) match {
  case List(x: Int, y: Int, *rest) =>
    println(rest) // i want to get List(3,4)
}
```

`_*` can **match** multiple variables but do to seem to be able to **capture** them.

Thanks!

Comment: `List(1,2,3,4) match { case ele1 :: ele2 :: rest => {} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rest @ _*` for this:

```
List(1,2,3,4) match {
  case List(x: Int, y: Int, rest @ _*) =>
    println(rest) 
}
```

Note that this is general: you can use `x @ pattern` to give the name `x` to any value matched by `pattern` (provided this value has a suitable type). See http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders.

Answer (score 2):

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) match {
  case _ :: _ :: tail => println(tail) // prints List(3, 4)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply match lists by cons operator:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) match { 
    case x :: y :: rest => println(rest) 
} // gives you "List(3, 4)" to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to invoke pattern matching on lists,

```
val List(x,y,rest @ _*) = List(1,2,3,4)
```

which extracts

```
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2
rest: Seq[Int] = List(3, 4)
```